# Convert String datetime to Date in java?

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to convert these two strings to date and I am getting exception unparseable date.

"2015-12-03T15:00:08.868987" and "2015-12-03T17:00:08Z".Tried these two formats
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" and "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

```
    String s = "2015-12-03T17:00:08Z";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    try
    {
        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(s);

        System.out.println("date : "+simpleDateFormat.format(date));
    }
    catch (ParseException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception "+ex);
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to parse a date without milliseconds and with a ISO-8601 time zone, using a format that requires milliseconds and a RFC 822 time zone. Please refer to the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28%29).

Comment: Slightly off topic but you may want to look at Joda-Time, it removes a lot of the frustrations associated with the core Java Date/Time classes

Comment: @LawrenceTierney The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library has been succeeded by the new java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34079900/642706) for discussion and examples of java.time code. If Java 8 technology is not available such as Android, then certainly Joda-Time is recommended as far superior to the old date-time classes bundled with early Java.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks. I _thought_ it had changed then convinced myself otherwise #longDay

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reason is you are using wrong format,here Z represents timezone

```
 String s = "2013-09-29T18:46:19-0700";
 SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

If time format is in above ,it will work fine.
If you just mark Z in single quotes,it will just consider as a String rather than parsing it.

Edit:-
If you want to use "2015-12-03T15:00:08.8689870",then pattern must be yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS

```
String s = "2015-12-03T15:00:08.8689870";
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

If date time is in 2015-12-03T17:00:08Z,then you can use pattern yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX where X denotes ISO 8601 time zone.The Java 7 version of SimpleDateFormat supports ISO-8601 time zones using the uppercase letter X.

```
String s = "2015-12-03T17:00:08Z";
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
Date dtIn = inFormat.parse(s);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

If you're stuck with Java 6 or earlier, the answer recommending JodaTime is a safe bet.

```
String timestamp = "2011-04-15T20:08:18Z";

DateTime dateTime = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseDateTime(timestamp);
```

This correctly recognizes the UTC timezone and allows you to then use Joda Time's extensive manipulation methods to get what you want out of it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thats what i have explained in my answer.That Z here denotes time zone,like GMT,etc..
So to use it,String must be in proper format....

Comment: @RealSkeptic its not necessary UTC,it can be any time zone ,either PDT,UTC,GMT,etc...

    String s = "2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT";
    SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss Z");

Comment: @RealSkeptic Updated the answer...There are two ways by which this can be acheived..Please refer answer

Comment: Please mark the answer as "ACCEPTED", if problem is solved.In this way, it will help others looking for similar problem.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    String s = "2015/12/03/17:00:34";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd/HH:mm:ss");
    try
    {
        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(s);

        System.out.println("date : "+simpleDateFormat.format(date));
    }
    catch (ParseException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception "+ex);
    }
```

Modify you String date same as the SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

Comment: No, because the `Z` has meaning in that date string. Adding a literal `'Z'` to the format string ignores that meaning (that is, that the date is in UTC, not a local date).

Answer (score 0):

The Pojava DateTime library (in Maven Central Repo) would parse both dates without needing to specify formats.

```
Date d1 = DateTime.parse("2015-12-03T15:00:08.868987").toDate();
Date d2 = DateTime.parse("2015-12-03T17:00:08Z").toDate();
System.out.println(d1); // Thu Dec 03 15:00:08 PST 2015
System.out.println(d2); // Thu Dec 03 09:00:08 PST 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

## Loss of Data

You are parsing a string input with six digits of fractional second, which means [microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond).

You are using the old java.sql.Date class which supports only milliseconds (3 digits). So even if you manage to parse that input, you will be losing some information.

## java.time

The classes you are using, `java.util.Date` & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, have been supplanted by the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

The java.time classes support [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution, up to 9 digits of fractional second. So no loss of data given your inputs.

## ISO 8601

Both of your String inputs are in the formats defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 by default when parsing or generating String representations of date-time values. So we can specify one of the predefined formatter rather than define a formatter pattern. For some formats we need not even bother specifying a formatter at all.

## Example Code

You have two input strings, so two examples.

### Example 1

The first string has no time zone or offset-from-UTC info. So we must specify a time by which to interpret the meaning of that input. I assume your intention was for [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). We specify UTC as the time zone by calling `withZone`.

That time zone is also assigned as the time zone of the `ZonedDateTime` object. In other words, no further time zone adjustment is made.

```
String input = "2015-12-03T15:00:08.868987";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withZone ( ZoneOffset.UTC );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input , formatter );
```

> zdt: 2015-12-03T15:00:08.868987Z

### Example 2

Your second string does contain time zone information, in the form of a `Z` which stands for `Zulu` and means `UTC`.

The java.time framework offers the `Instant` class to represent a moment on the timeline in UTC. You can think of a `ZonedDateTime` as being an `Instant` plus a time zone (`ZoneId`).

Because this second string is (a) in UTC time zone, and (b) in ISO 8601 format, we need not specify any formatter. The `Instant` class can directly parse such a String.

```
String input = "2015-12-03T17:00:08Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse ( input );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant );
```

> instant: 2015-12-03T17:00:08Z